# how to enable ssr on Rails 6 app with webpacker and React

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, server-side-rendering

I'm guessing that since newly scaffolded Rails apps use webpacker, adding a gem like react rails would be an anti-pattern. that said, is there a canonical way to enable ssr on a rails app with react or would I need to run node as well for this?

Answer (score 1):

I recently went through trying the 3 popular solutions:

1. Rails + Webpacker
2. Rails + Webpacker + react_on_rails
3. Rails + Webpacker + react-rails

react_on_rails opinion... It doesn't use integration tests that can use RSpec (Capybara) to combine both React + Rails environments. Both webpack and rails server are running via the foreman gem, which means you'd have to add *another* complex configuration to have RSpec integration tests that traverse both. There is also way too many settings that I was already configuring myself (Docker, Heroku, to name a couple...). The commit history the past year is also mostly doc changes (looking now this past couple weeks there has been some activity, though). Also it promotes a "Pro" edition, which kinda turned me off tbh.

react-rails is much more light-weight and was just easier to get working. The team is the official React team (reactjs.org). It "just worked" for me.

If you need a starting point, I'd recommend checking out this Rails starter kit that is built as a Rails + React setup:

https://github.com/patrickclery/dry-rails-react

Particularly these files:

- babel.config.js
- app/javascript/packs/application.js
- app/javascript/packs/server_rendering.js
- package.json
- config/webpacker.yml

Answer (score 0):

The gems are just another option, wondering why you see this gem in rails as an anti-pattern as there is a section in the react-rails gem documentation [specific to webpacker](https://github.com/reactjs/react-rails/blob/master/README.md#get-started-with-webpacker). It clearly describes how to use the react-rails gem with Webpacker.

Here's another [pretty up-to-date resource](https://learnetto.com/blog/react-rails), which provides examples for

- Webpacker
- react-rails
- react_on_rails

For **webpacker** it says:

> All files in the new app/javascript/packs directory are compiled by Webpack.

For **react-rails** it says:

> react-rails is the official React community gem for integrating React with Rails. The main benefit of using this gem is the react_component helper method which makes it easy to pass Rails data to components.
>   react-rails also gives you the option to continue using the default Rails asset pipeline to serve your React code, instead of using webpacker

For the third option **react_on_rails** it says:

> The other most popular third-party gem for integrating React into Rails is the react_on_rails gem created by ShakaCode.
>   Similar to the react-rails gem, now that Rails already provides an easy way to use React via webpacker, you have to see if the stated benefits of the react_on_rails gem apply to your situation.